# Do Maps SDK for Android needs a billing enabled api key?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a BILLING NOT ENABLED project. and have a api key with that... i'm using this api key in my android project to render maps with MapView. But it seems in the documentation, it is mentioned that maps sdk for android needs a billing enabled api key... but in my case it is working fine without billing enabled... i'm i doing something wrong? or it will break when go to production?

Comment: Supposedly, it should not work according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start#get-key). You could try verifying it by generating another API key with no billing account and try it again on your app, or you could try that same API key with another API.

Comment: @Yrll The same api key fails when calling direction / places api... but works for rendering the map alone.

Comment: Have you checked the restrictions you set? But anyways, since this is a non coding related question, and more about billing, I suggest you file a support case on Google Maps Platform if you have an active billing account. So that they could look further into it.